# Process Block Not Work in Graphics.DrawString

Tags: windows, powershell, object, graphics

I have a PowerShell function (`out()`). When I want to get a result from pipeline into an `image`, it takes the last object from the pipeline. For example: I want to show all objects in (`gps`):

```
function out {
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
    [parameter(
        Mandatory = $true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
    [string[]]
    $n
)



    Process {
    $dirname = Get-Location | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
    $filename = $(Get-Date -f "yyyy-mm-dd--hh-mm-ss-tt") + "--image.png"
    $ImagePath = $dirname + "\" + $filename

      ForEach ($input in $n) {

        #PUT Your Image:
         $basefilename = "D:\ZalansDB\imgs\main\bg_D.jpg"
            $bmp = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile("$basefilename")

            $font = new-object System.Drawing.Font ('Microsoft Sans Serif',16)
            $fcolors = [System.Drawing.Brushes]
            $graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

            $graphics.DrawString($input,$font,$fcolors::White,30,40)


            $filename = $ImagePath
            $graphics.Dispose() 
            $bmp.Save($filename)
         } 




            Invoke-Item $filename 


    } 



}

Get-Process | Select-Object -First 2 | out
```

**Result**:
[image]

I want to show First 2 prcoess objects into my image

Comment: You are always drawing to the same location (30, 40) so you'll never see more than one result. Is that intentional?

Comment: Bruce Payette!, oh are you real `Bruce Payette`?! Who is my dream person? I don't believe that. thank you sir.

Comment: Your filenames are not unique. If you put a sleep in there for a second it works because it allows the names to change. I would also use the begin block for things that you only need to set once.

Comment: @Matt I don't think so, because if I did that, for each object it will take an image. I want to all objects shows in from single image.

Comment: Oh? That was not clear to me. You want all of the processes, as text, in one image file? you should collect them all at once and them join them with new lines.

Comment: Yes sir, Sorry. or maybe -First 2 and so on

Comment: Aso - yes I'm the real Bruce Payette :-) Nice to meet you! It seems like @Matt has done a nice job with your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see loads of valid approaches for this. Use `begin` block to set the variables that are not going to change. Use the `process` block to collect the process names. Finally, use `end` to display the image. We use `-join` to get them all in one string so we don't have to redraw, and manage locations, all the time.

```
function Set-ProcessPicture{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias("ProcessName")]
        $Process,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        $BaseImagePath = "d:\temp\test.jpg"
    )


    begin{
        $dirname = Get-Location | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
        $font = new-object System.Drawing.Font ('Microsoft Sans Serif',16)
        $fcolors = [System.Drawing.Brushes]
        $baseBitmap = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($BaseImagePath)
        $graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($baseBitmap)

        $outputString = @()
    }

    Process {
        $outputString += $process
    } 
    end {
        $graphics.DrawString(($outputString -join "`r`n"),$font,$fcolors::White,30,40)
        $filename = [io.path]::Combine((Get-Location).Path,(Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss-fff") + "--image.png")
        $graphics.Dispose() 
        $baseBitmap.Save($filename)

        Invoke-Item $filename 
    }

}

Get-Process | Select-Object -First 2 | Set-ProcessPicture
```

[image: Sample Output]

I made a few best practice code changes. This is not how I would leave it but corrects the issue that you were having.

**Note:** Use MM for months in your format strings

Comment: thank you, can we get same result of 'gps | select -f 2' as like console? I mean if you type above cmdlet you got a different result. I want to take same console result into picture. thank yo

Comment: If you want to do that then you can pipe into Out-String which would get you a string just like the console. Doing so kinda negates the pipeline function though

Comment: I'm use: $outputString += $process | out-string, but it shows each of result in my picture

Comment: thank you I fixed that, by changing this line: `$graphics.DrawString(($outputString | Out-String), $font, $fcolors::White, 930, 100)` - thank you gain